# Saving a struct with fwrite

Tags: c++

I have the following structs:

```
struct Layer
{
    node fileInfo;
    std::vector<int> fadePoints;
    std::vector<int> syncPoints;
    float vol;
    PatternSet *pUp;
};
struct node
{
    union{
        struct{
            std::string filename;
            void *padding;
        };
        struct{
            void *data;
            unsigned int len;
        };
    };
};
```

Can i simply save the Layer struct using `fwrite()` when i have guarantee that node will always use first unnamed struct,`padding` will be always `nullptr` and `pUp` is not important(can be discarded)?

I'm not sure about vectors if they can be saved like that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. When you use fwrite() you save the binary representation of data - this function doesn't care what the data is. If it's a union it doesn't care - it just saves bytes from memory.
2. You cannot save vectors like that, because all you would save is a bunch of pointers to dynamically allocated memory. The same is true for std::string.